# Why does first IF statement have a performance hit in C#?

Tags: c#

I did some testing, wanting to optimize the IF logic for the least performance hit. Here's what's bizarre. Whichever IF statement I put first in the code would perform 3-7 times worse than the follow-up IF statement. At first I thought this meant the short-circuit of the "&&" clause in stopWatch1 IF statement was less efficient (As shown below).

```
Stopwatch stopWatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
if (ShowMonthBeginningIsSelected &&
    daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month >= 1 &&
    daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month <= 12 &&
    daysToDisplay[i].Day.DayOfMonth == 1)
    {
    stopWatch1.Stop();
    }
long elapsedTime1 = stopWatch1.ElapsedTicks;

Stopwatch stopWatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
if (ShowMonthBeginningIsSelected)
   {
   if (daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month >= 1 &&
       daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month <= 12 &&
       daysToDisplay[i].Day.DayOfMonth == 1)
       {
       stopWatch2.Stop();
       }
   }
long elapsedTime2 = stopWatch2.ElapsedTicks;
```

However, when I flipped the IF statements to confirm the result, the IF statement inside stopWatch2 would perform 3-7 times worse than the IF statement inside stopWatch1 (As shown below).

```
Stopwatch stopWatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
if (ShowMonthBeginningIsSelected)
   {
   if (daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month >= 1 &&
       daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month <= 12 &&
       daysToDisplay[i].Day.DayOfMonth == 1)
       {
       stopWatch2.Stop();
       }
   }
long elapsedTime2 = stopWatch2.ElapsedTicks;

Stopwatch stopWatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
if (ShowMonthBeginningIsSelected &&
    daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month >= 1 &&
    daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month <= 12 &&
    daysToDisplay[i].Day.DayOfMonth == 1)
    {
    stopWatch1.Stop();
    }
long elapsedTime1 = stopWatch1.ElapsedTicks;
```

This leads to my question:

Why does the first question take such a significant performance hit?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers for profilers to use.

Comment: While profilers mentioned by @Progman are useful for debugging the problem, for the [mre] make sure to use BenchmarkDotNet rather than homegrown solutions. (make sure to read classical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array just in case - I have not read your question carefully enough yet to know if it applies directly, but good info on conditionals in the code)

Comment: (Presumably asking for tools recommendations - which is off-topic on SO - is not your goal. Make sure to [edit] out that part)

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons for this beyond anything to do with your actual code, including caching of both the data & the command in the CPU cache.  So that subsequent executions are therefore much quicker (the purpose of a cache).  Don't try to over optimise your code.

Comment: The profiler question seemed relevant if I'm not supposed to use a StopWatch. I have edited the comment down to the question I really cared about. @AlexeiLevenkov

Out of curiosity, why is asking about profilers "off-topic"? I just read the meta thread bemoaning a lack of quality questions, and went to great lengths to ensure this question would be both specific to me, and helpful for future readers. Profilers seems like something helpful for others.

Comment: Ok, so I think you're saying there is no code-based performance difference between these two?  Thanks for the answer! - @jason.kaisersmith

Comment: The reason may be in [JIT compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-execution-process#compilation-by-the-jit-compiler).

Comment: Interesting. That's worth remembering. Am I wrong to think this example would be native code for a Windows desktop application, being built in .NET MAUI? Thank you for your answer and time. - @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: @RAB if you have questions/problems with https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic please asks those questions on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You are doing these comparisons in a release build, right?

Comment: You use: `stopWatch1.Stop();` in both `if` sentences! That means that `stopWatch1`will ALWAYS stop first.

Comment: @PoulBak: I'm pretty sure that must be a transcription error, because it causes a compilation error in the second code block.

Comment: Ah yes, Ben Voigt is correct, that was a transcription error. I've edited the question. Good catch, though. Thanks! - @PoulBak

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this check looks extra:

```
    daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month >= 1 &&
    daysToDisplay[i].Day.Month <= 12 &&
```

I suspect what `Month` can't be out of 1 to 12 range here. If not, it looks strange, but it's up to the author.

Another concern to check:

```
var dtd = daysToDisplay[i].Day;
Stopwatch stopWatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
if (ShowMonthBeginningIsSelected && dtd.Month >= 1 &&
  dtd.Month <= 12 && dtd.DayOfMonth == 1) stopWatch1.Stop();

long elapsedTime1 = stopWatch1.ElapsedTicks;

Stopwatch stopWatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
if (ShowMonthBeginningIsSelected)
 if (dtd.Month >= 1 && dtd.Month <= 12 && dtd.DayOfMonth == 1)
   stopWatch2.Stop();

long elapsedTime2 = stopWatch2.ElapsedTicks;
```

Comment: Oh, it wouldn't be obvious in the information provided, but some values in the "Month" can exceed 12. That's the purpose of this check. But, I'm more asking on a principle level, and not to specifically optimize this exact code. Thanks for your time! - rotabor

Comment: Another concern to check.